# Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities while getting records using range dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

i have develop a small web application in that i want get the records from database using Entity frame work when get the records it showing error ..

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities. 

   public void Bindloanpayment()
    {
        int loanpaymentid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Loanid"].ToString());
         int kr = 1998;
        int km = 05;
        int kdt = 02;

         var query = from p in mortgageentity.Payments
                        join D in mortgageentity.Debit_Method on p.Debit_Method_ID equals D.Debit_Method_ID
                        join pt in mortgageentity.Payment_Type on p.Payment_Type_ID equals pt.Payment_Type_ID
                     where (p.Client_Pmt_Date >= new DateTime(kr, km, kdt)) && (p.Client_Pmt_Date <= new DateTime(1999, 8, 1)) && (p.Loan_ID == loanpaymentid)
                        select new
                    {
                       Pmt_ID=p.Pmt_ID,
                       Loan_ID=p.Loan_ID,
                       Client_Pmt_Date=p.Client_Pmt_Date,
                       MtgSvr_Pmt_Start_Date2=p.MtgSvr_Pmt_Start_Date2,
                       Debit_Method_Desc=D.Debit_Method_Desc,
                       Total_Debit_Amt=p.Total_Debit_Amt,
                       CreditAmt=p.CreditAmt,
                       LenderAmt=p.LenderAmt,
                       Payment_Type_Desc=pt.Payment_Type_Desc,
                       Return_Code=p.Return_Code,
                       Returned_Date=p.Returned_Date

                    };
        grdPayments.DataSource = query.ToList();
        grdPayments.DataBind();

    }
```

Please help me how can i resolve this problem..

Comment: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities. this is i got error.

Comment: Ok, how you tried Jon Skeets solution. It seems possible that you can't init new items inside lambda code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating the `DateTime` values first:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(kr, km, kdt);
DateTime end = new DateTime(1999, 8, 1);

...
// In the query
where p.Client_Pmt_Date >= start
   && p.Client_Pmt_Date <= end 
   && p.Loan_ID == loanpaymentid
```

That's only a guess as to what's going wrong, but it seems feasible...